# NodeHandle namespaces

Tags: ros, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just an question about a very specific corner-case of the `NodeHandle` API, that is not covered by its documentation. I have no bug for you to solve or anything, I just need to know whether the scenario I'm describing in a second is possible, for my Master Thesis.

So, in this C++ code snippet

```
using namespace ros;
...
NodeHandle nh("outer_namespace/inner_namespace");
```

a `NodeHandle` is specifying a nested namespace in its constructor. Does `outer_namespace` have to exist *before* `nh` is constructed, or will it be created on the spot? In other words, can `NodHandle` define a hierarchy of namespaces, or should all but the rightmost namespace exist at creation time?

Basically, does `NodeHandle nh("outer_namespace/inner_namespace");` behave like the UNIX command `mkdir outer_namespace/inner_namespace` or like `mkdir -p outer_namespace/inner_namespace`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304682/nodehandle-namespaces/) by [dlae](https://answers.ros.org/users/37876/dlae/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

namespaces don't "exist", they're just prefixes on names (ie: strings) and the semantics are given to them by humans.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1